# flutter java.lang.StackOverflowError (no error message)

Tags: android, flutter

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  java.lang.StackOverflowError (no error message)
- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

Can anyone please tell me how to fix it?

i ran the code code in debug consele this appeared:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  java.lang.StackOverflowError (no error message)
- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

Can anyone please tell me how to fix it?

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please mention what were you doing and what was expected when this happened.